# Update a column in a parent entity based on a column in child entities in Dataverse

Tags: dataverse, power-platform

What is the best approach for summarizing an amount on a Parent entity based on it's Child entities. For example, Invoice and Invoice Item.

Invoice Item entity has a column called Price.

I would like the Invoice entity to have a column called Price that would be a summation of all the Invoice Item Prices.

My thought is to use a Power Automate flow to do this, but wonder if there is another way? I looked at Rollup columns, but seems those run on a internal, defaulting to once a day.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to summarizing an amount on a parent entity is to create a rollup column.

The purpose of a rollup column is to make an aggregation of child entities values like a count, a sum, a min / max, etc...

In your example, you should create a rollup into the Invoice entity and configure it to summarize the Price of all children that are Invoice Item.

To do this, you can go on your [PowerApps Admin Portal](https://make.powerapps.com) and click on the Tables menu

Then go find your Invoice entity and click on Columns under the Schema section then click on "New Column".

Create a column of type Currency (or whatever the type of the Price column is) and make it a Rollup behaviour.

Then, on the settings popup, add Invoice Item as a link entity and add a SUM aggregation on Price.

This is a tutorial you can follow to create a rollup column.
[Rollup field tutorial](https://carldesouza.com/dynamics-365-rollup-fields/#:%7E:text=Rollup%20fields%20are%20a%20field%20type%20in%20Dynamics,Go%20to%20the%20entity%20and%20select%20New%20Field.)

And the documentation
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/define-rollup-fields?view=op-9-1)

Please note that rollup fields are automatically calculated by Dynamics every X hours (it is configurable somewhere but can't remember where). But you can force it by clicking on the field or by code.
If you need to know how, you can follow the tutorial below.
[How to force rollup field update](https://www.crmcrate.com/plugin/programmatically-trigger-a-rollup-field-in-dynamics-crm/)

Good luck =)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).